# DQN with multiple actions taken at same time-step for differents joints for robot control

Tags: controls, reinforcement-learning, robotics, dqn

I am trying to teach a double pendulum fully actuated to perform a swing-up maneuver and keep the position if it reaches it. I previously trained a single pendulum with DQN and it learned the policy well in just a couple of hours of training.
Now the problem is that I have a robot with two joints, so two actions must be chosen at the same time: the torque for the first one and the torque for the second one.
The only method that comes to me is to generate the Q value for each possible action pair. The problem with this is that the action space grows exponentially with the joint space.
Is there any other way to solve the problem?